# UIHInt template conflicts with defautl editor templates MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view, whose controls I am trying to render using UIHInt data annotation attributes.

For the string properties in model, I have used UIHint("TextBox") and added a TextBox.cshtml in my shared/editortemplates folder, this is working fine and shows the desired textbox I want from my txt.js.

I followed the same way to show my datetime control (jquery widget datetime picker).
I have used UIHInt("DFDateTime") for datetimeoffset properties in model and added DFDateTime.cshtml in shared/editor templates folder.

Getting the exception: 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.DateTimeOffset', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

I dont know why this error is coming, can somebody advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know why this error is coming, can somebody advise?

Use the appropriate model type in your `DFDateTime.cshtml` template:

```
@model DateTimeOffset
...
```

Comment: ,thanks for reply..I dont understand why should I use like this.I have not used anything similar in my TextBox.cshtml but that still works.

Comment: That's probably because the property you used for your textbox is a string.